# NetBeans - has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, netbeans

I am facing the error, when compiling and running java in NetBeans 12 for Spring Boot 3.0.3 & Java 17.

**java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/example/javareacttemplate/MainClass has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0**

I was trying to create a simple maven project to print the Java runtime version next to that project and it successfully ran with the output:

```
 System.out.println("Java v:" + System.getProperty("java.version"));
 //Java v:17.0.6
```

And these are 2 terminal commands at the beginning of running 2 projects

The Spring Boot one

```
cd D:\somepath\somepath\projectOne; 
"JAVA_HOME=D:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-17" 
M2_HOME=D:\\Maven\\apache-maven-3.9.0 cmd /c "\"D:\\Maven\\apache-maven-3.9.0\\bin\\mvn.cmd\" 
-Dexec.args=\"-classpath %classpath com.example.javareacttemplate.MainClass\" 
-Dexec.executable=java 
-Dexec.classpathScope=runtime 
-Dmaven.ext.class.path=\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans-12.0\\netbeans\\java\\maven-nblib\\netbeans-eventspy.jar\" 
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec"
```

The simple Maven project

```
cd D:\somepath\somepath\somepath\mavenproject1; 
"JAVA_HOME=D:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-17" 
M2_HOME=D:\\Maven\\apache-maven-3.9.0 cmd /c "\"D:\\Maven\\apache-maven-3.9.0\\bin\\mvn.cmd\" 
-Dexec.args=\"-classpath %classpath com.mycompany.mavenproject1.MainClass\" 
-Dexec.executable=\"D:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-17\\bin\\java.exe\" 
-Dexec.classpathScope=runtime 
-Dmaven.ext.class.path=\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans-12.0\\netbeans\\java\\maven-nblib\\netbeans-eventspy.jar\" 
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec"
```

I don't know how to change the Spring Boot Java run time, is there any way possible to change it to 17 but still use NetBeans IDE?

Update: in Help -> About tab
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this problem by choosing JAR Packaging instead of WAR at the beginning of Spring Initializr.

Comment: It's good that you resolved your issue, but note that [NetBeans 12.0 does not support the use of JDK 17](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb120/nb120.html): _"Apache NetBeans 12.0 runs on the JDK LTS releases 8 and 11, as well as on JDK 14"_. [Upgrade to the latest release, NetBeans 17](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb17/), if you want to use JDK 17 or JDK 19.

Comment: I have realized that NetBeans 12 uses Java 8 as the runtime and can't be changed to 17 when choosing WAR file packaging.